# Error in combined bar chart and line chart creation using achart engine in android

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine, linechart

I am doing chart applications using achart engine for my application. I created bar chart, dual line chart and line chart . Now i am doing combined chart for bar and line charts.  . But i got some error on this code.

Comment: Your solution in your error **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1**.. your list size is 1 and you using index number 1 thats why you facing error .. list index start from 0

Answer (score 1):

i am Not Sure but you Should Replace the

```
values.add(new double[] { 5000,4000,3100,2000,200,-1200,-300,200,1000,200,500,200});
```

with

```
 for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {

     values.add(new double[] { 5000,4000,3100,2000,200,-1200,-300,200,1000,200,500,200});
 }
```

Comment: i got the answer i did some silly mistake . Any way thank for your valuable time

Answer (score 1):

Yes i got the answer . I did some silly mistake in the following line

```
     String[] titles = new String[] { "Actual", "Budget" };
```

Actually here i have to give one option. So its obviously arise ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException . 
 Thank you all.